# Can someone please advise with a simple -ldapfilter

Tags: powershell

Hi all can someone help me understand why the resulting exported file does not contain any information. For each ISID (the ackronym for my setup's log in name) in the  imported .csv file, I want to find the corresponding samAccountName and export the listed properties...

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
connect-qadservice US2.k.com -proxy
$groupName = Import-csv c:\ExportDL\LockedAccounts.csv
write-host "This window will close when done"_ADmembers.csv" will be created" -ForegroundColor Green
ForEach ($ISID in $groupName) {
get-qaduser -ldapfilter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$ISID))" 
    -includedproperties samAccountName,accountExpires,edsvaParentCanonicalName,edsaAccountIsDisabled,passwordLastset,department,manager,distinguishedName,displayName | 
    select edsvaParentCanonicalName,displayName,samAccountName,name,edsaAccountIsDisabled,logonName,
    lastName,firstName,manager,accountExpires,passwordLastset | 
        export-csv C:\ExportDL\LockedAccounts_ADmembers.csv
}
```

My apologies for the bad indentation. I cant figure the four spaces code block out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but will be interesting know the content of `LockedAccounts.csv` file:

```
Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
connect-qadservice US2.k.com -proxy
$groupName = Import-csv c:\ExportDL\LockedAccounts.csv 
write-host "This window will close when done"_ADmembers.csv" will be created" -Fore Green

( $groupName | select -expa ISID | get-qaduser -includedproperties samAccountName,accountExpires,ParentCanonicalName,
AccountIsDisabled,passwordLastset, department,manager,distinguishedName,displayName | 
select ParentCanonicalName,displayName,samAccountName,name,AccountIsDisabled,logonName,
       lastName,firstName,manager,accountExpires,passwordLastset ) |
export-csv C:\ExportDL\LockedAccounts_ADmembers.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If the `ISID` column contains `sAMAccountName` there is not need for a `ldap query`, the `QADs` command accept it as input via `pipe` or for `-identity` parameter